# install tryton on centos 7 for gnu health but i can't run gnuhealth client and tryton client

Tags: python, centos, gtk, centos7, tryton

when i run $tryton it shows me this
the same for $ gnuhealth-client

$ tryton

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tryton", line 52, in <module>
    from tryton.client import main
  File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tryton/client.py", li                                                         ne 12, in <module>
    from tryton import gui
  File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tryton/gui/__init__.p                                                         y", line 3, in <module>
    from .main import *
  File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tryton/gui/main.py",                                                          line 33, in <module>
    from tryton.gui.window.activity import Activity
  File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tryton/gui/window/act                                                         ivity.py", line 23, in <module>
    class Activity():
  File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tryton/gui/window/act                                                         ivity.py", line 25, in Activity
    activity_window = Gtk.Window()
  File "/home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py",                                                          line 521, in __init__
    "Gtk couldn't be initialized. "
RuntimeError: Gtk couldn't be initialized. Use Gtk.init_check() if you want to h                                                         andle this case.
```

what shopuld i do ?

this is the output of check init

gnuhealth@ghealth:~ $  python -c 'from gi.repository import Gtk'
-c:1: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
gnuhealth@ghealth:~ $ Gtk.init_check()

> ^C

Comment: can you post output of `python -c 'from gi.repository import Gtk'; Gtk.init_check()`?

Comment: gnuhealth@ghealth:~ $ python -c 'from gi.repository import Gtk' -c:1: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded. gnuhealth@ghealth:~ $ Gtk.init_check()  > (empty file i guess)